# How to detect screen on the image?

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, neural-network, image-segmentation

I need to detect a screen on the photo. It can be a laptopt screen, tv, etc. For now, I use tensorflow's [deeplab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) to get a mask, and then opencv to get corners.
It works ok, but I'm pretty sure there should be a better wayto do it. All I need is to get those 4 corners or an array of fourths. Maybe I could use another model to remove the opencv part?

That's how it looks now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Post with a few different sample input images.